# Entity Framework Code First Adding a null value for a id column

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I am using Entity Framework code first and ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have the following context defined:

```
public class PbeContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
     {
          dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
     }
}
```

My Category class:

```
public class Category
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
     public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
     public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

`ParentCategoryId` in my `Category table` is a foreign key that is linked to the Id (Category Id) column.

On my create view there is a drop drown list displaying all the parent categories.  You don't have to select a parent category.  If none is selected then it means that you are creating/capturing a parent category.

How I normally did it in the past is if the user does not select a parent category from the drop down list then I would make `ParentCategoryId` in my `Category` table `NULL`.  Currently it is trying to add 0 to the table and failing because there is no category with and Id of 0.  Is it still best practices to add it as a `NULL` value if no parent category is selected?  If so, how would I do it using Entity Framework code first?

**EDIT**

I have changed the int in my view model and Category class to nullable as suggested.

```
public class CreateCategoryViewModel
{
    public CreateCategoryViewModel()
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }

     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
     public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public SelectList ParentCategoriesSelectList { get; set; }
     public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

My updated category class:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

My dropdown list has a default "-- Select --" option with a value of 0.  When I click submit the ParentCategoryId in the view model is 0.  I map it to the category class and the ParentCategoryId is still zero.  When and how is this converted to NULL?  The error that I am still getting is:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_Category_Category". The conflict occurred in database "ProgrammingByExample", table "dbo.Category", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `ParentCategoryId` nullable

```
public class Category
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
     public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
     public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Edit

> My dropdown list has a default "-- Select --" option with a value of 0

The default option should not have a value(you have put 0)
Eg:

```
@Html.DropDownFor(model => model.ParentCategoryId, 
    (SelectList)ViewBag.ParentCategories, "-- Select --")
```

Comment: Is this the best way to do it? Is it a wise choice to make an int nullable? Just want to hear your opinion.

Comment: @Brendan yes. that's how its usually done. (other method is to completely remove the scalar property `ParentCategoryId` and map it accordingly.)

Comment: @Brendan: It is actually the only way to do that. So yes it is wise.